# What does it mean for a linear operator to converge to another linear operator?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I am currently studying linear algebra, and I am having a trouble understanding convergence of a linear operator. Specifically,

Let $\Omega \subset L(\mathbb R^n)$ be the collection of all invertible linear operators, where $L$ stands for linear operator. Let $A, B \in \Omega$.

The book says $||A-B|| \rightarrow 0$ as $B \rightarrow A$. I am having a trouble understanding $B \rightarrow A$. Sure, $B$ and $A$ are linear operators so they can be represented by matrices form, so that I can make $||M_B - M_A||$ be very small so that perturbation will be very small. However, without resorting to thinking in terms of matrices, how can I interpret $B \rightarrow A$ in terms of linear operators?

Also, would the same conclusion hold if I am working in a linear operator in some space $X$, not necessarily Euclidean?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be answered quite easily: Let $X, Y$ be some finite-dimensional (we are in linear algebra), normed $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces and $A:X \rightarrow Y$ a linear operator.
Usually, one defines the so called operator norm
$$
\lVert A \rVert := \sup_{\lVert x \rVert_X = 1} \lVert Ax \rVert_Y. 
$$

It is nontrivial that $\lVert A \rVert < \infty$. This comes from Heine-Borels theorem of the unit ball being compact in finite-dimensional spaces.
This norm has some nice properties, e.g. $\lVert Ax \rVert \leq \lVert A \rVert \lVert x \rVert_X$ for all $x \in X$. There are a lot more of those and you should take a look at them.

Do also note that because $X$ and $Y$ are finite-dimensional, there exist isomorphisms $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\dim X}$ and $Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\dim Y}$. So your thinking can always be in terms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ - at least in the finite-dimensional case.

Now, some intuition: Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ have the norm $\displaystyle \lVert x \rVert_{\infty} := \max_{k = 1, ..., n} \lvert x_k \rvert$. One can show that the induced operator norm is given by
$$
\lVert A \rVert := \max_{i = 1, ..., n} \sum_{j = 1}^n \lvert  a_{ij} \rvert
$$
for some matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Now let's look at some matrix sequence $B^{(k)}$ that satisfies $b^{(k)}_{ij} \rightarrow b_{ij}$ for all $i, j \in \lbrace 1, ..., n \rbrace$ and some numbers $b_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $B := (b_{ij})_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}$. Then:
$$
\lVert B^{(k)} - B \rVert = \max_{i = 1, ..., n} \sum_{j = 1}^n \left\lvert  b_{ij}^{(k)} - b_{ij} \right\rvert \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 \quad (\text{by definition})
$$
All norms on finite-dimensional spaces (so all operator norms on $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$) are equivalent. This means that convergence in one of them implies convergence in all the others. So a matrix converging entry-wise always implies convergence in the operator norm.
Check for yourself if the opposite is true.

If you are really interested in this then you should read a book about functional analysis. Linear operators would make a rather small portion of it.

Comment: It was an awesome answer! Thank you! To make sure I fully understood, what you essentially mean is: given an invertible linear operator $B$, you transform $B$ to a matrix $M$, and create a sequence of matrix $M^k$ that converges to $M$ in $|| \cdot ||_\infty$. Then, convert $M^k$ back to $B^k$. Since all norms are equivalent, I get a conclusion that $B^k \rightarrow B$.

Comment: I am aware of the result that all norms are equivalent, but it is sheer magic  for me that two seemingly unrelated norms are equivalent, i.e. $||A|| := \sup |Ax|$ is equivalent to $||A||_\infty$.

Comment: Not quite, the matrices were just some example. I used that if there is convergence in the $\infty$-matrix-norm then there is convergence in all matrix norms. By that I demonstrated that if matrices converge entry-wise then they converge in ANY matrix norm (there are a lot more than the one I showed you). This was just an example but bear in mind that there is a matrix representation for any linear operator on a finite-dimensional space with finite-dimensional image. To only calculate the norm, you do not even need that as the definition of the norm should work just fine for you.

Comment: The equivalent norms are less unrelated than you think. I really recommend you to look up the proof, it is one fascinating result.

Comment: I see. I have slightly edited the question immediately after posting the question. So we relied on $\infty$-matrix norm to find out the convergence of $B_k \rightarrow B$. However without resorting to matrix, is there a way to interpret convergence of $B_k \rightarrow B$ in an abstract space of invertible linear operators?

Comment: I can define $B_k$ to satisfy the following property: $\forall x \in S^n$, $|(B - B_k)x| < \epsilon$. This gives a nice definition of $B_k$, but how do I know the existence of such $B_k \in \Omega$, where $B_k \neq B$, in the first place?

Comment: Sorry for answering late. The only way to do that is to find the representation matrix of the linear operator $B$. To fully understand convergence in operator norm you have to read books on functional analysis.

Comment: If $B$ is invertible, then you can always find a $B_K$ with $\lVert B - B_k \rVert < \varepsilon$: Because the set $(- \infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\det$ (which is a polynomial) is continuous, the set $\Omega = \det^{-1}((-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty))$ is open in the space of linear operators. The other case I am not entirely sure about...

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!